# Distinct() method is not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ similar to this:

```
var list = (from g in myPreBuiltQuery
            where g.Address != null
            orderby g.Schools.SchoolName
            select new ResultFindSummary
            {
               // fill some fields for this class
            }).Take(100).Distinct().ToArray();
```

But still it is returning extra duplicate results.

Comment: Can you post the code for `ResultFindSummary`?

Comment: And which fields should be different ?

Comment: A grid of expected result and actual results would also help in this case.

Comment: Have you overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? Apart from that, i would swap the `Take` and `Distinct` if you want up to 100 distinct results.

Comment: You state that you have a LINQ query **similar** to the one above.  What is your **actual** LINQ query?  Are you materializing your results to a C# collection before calling `.Distinct()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinct uses an IEqualityComparer on items in memory.
Now you are making a distinction on an sql query which is probably translated wrongly. (You can inspect that with the SQL profiler).

Two possible solutions => use groupby in combination with a first. If you want to work on the sql directly.

Or use the distinct after you converted your result set to memory (using .ToList()) and implement the IEqualityComparer on the SomeClass.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're creating 100 different instances of a custom type (`ResultFindSummary`), and that instances of a custom type are only considered equal when they reference the same object.

The solution is to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods in the `ResultFindSummary` class.

Answer (score 2):

Have you implemented the Equals method in your ResultFindSummary class ?

Here is a topic from MSDN on how to Distinct() function works : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a Distinct on a ResultFindSummary object. To use Distinct on an object you would need to use the Distinct override (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that provides a class that implements the IEqualityComparer interface...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx